# Designing a step-up transformer

Tags: power-supply, transformer

I'm designing a new transformer for a project I'm building. I trying to design a new product the primary produces has 2 connections and makes 0.8A. I want to step-up  to one coil and need to produce at least 20A. The 2 primaries have 12000 winds, how many winds do I need for my secondary to produce the amount of power I'm looking for?
Really what I need to know is how many winds are required to step-up by a hundred... My two primaries have 12,000 a piece. I have 0.8A on the primary which is 0.4 volts, and I'm looking to get at least 20 volts... Enough to support something like a 12 volt battery. My primary circuit makes 0.8 amps with a 0.5 ohm resister and the equation I learned in h vac class is amps multiplied by resistance equals volts. And my source makes its own alternating current.

- voltage equation:
  Amps X Resistance = Volts

Comment: I am going to vote to close this question as "unclear what your asking". There are a number of problems with what you have written that need serious correction. (1) A step up transformer is normally used to increase the voltage from the primary to a higher voltage on the secondary. You have made no mention of voltages at all. (2) Primary windings on a transformer are typically driven from a power source that would deliver current to the winding. Your saying that the "primaries produce 0.4 amps" makes no sense in this context. (3) Lastly be aware that the transformer (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) will never be more than 100% efficient. The input volts x amps (i.e VA) will always be a bit higher than the output volts x amps (VA).

Comment: Thank you for your input... I've reworded the question I just hope nobody steals my idea.

Comment: Your edits have done nothing to address the issues I raised. The close vote remains.

Comment: @D.Palmer2: Can you write the basic equation relating input and output voltages and currents for us so that we know that you know the basics of transformer theory? Your most recent edit is still missing a proper transformer specification.

Comment: Can you message my phone the application of my system is something I'm in the process of inventing... My number is (417) 403-8647

Comment: I don't want to risk having my ideas stolen because I shared too much information

Comment: You are looking for something that takes in 0.8A x 0.4V = 0.32W, and produces 20A x 20V = 400W.  That can't be done.  It violates some fundamental laws of physics.

Comment: Is there a private chat room on this app... I would like to explain what I'm trying to do but don't want too many people to know... It's something experimental... And if I succeed I'll be a great success

Comment: In your most recent edit you have added a version of Ohm's Law. This is not relevant to transformers so it appears that you don't understand very basic transformer theory. It seems very unlikely that you have invented anything. Instead it reads as though you think you have discovered some system that gives out more energy than you put in. This is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a **step-up** transformer that provides 20A if your primaries provide just 0.8A total. The amount of power out must be less than the power in. If you want 20A then you will have a secondary voltage that is no more than 1/25 of the primary voltage, and the secondary will have 1/25 as many turns as the primary.

Comment: With the product I'm building I will actually have 2 transformers the will supply one outside circuit is that possible?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. What is "one outside circuit"?

Comment: It's going to be an Amplifier